# MYsql - ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando rodar :

`mysql.server start`

e me retorna

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
>   (/usr/local/var/mysql/user.pid).

Tentei rodar:

`unset TMPDIR 
 mysql_install_db`

mas me retornou:

> [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to
>   mysqld --initialize [ERROR]   The data directory needs to be
>   specified.

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

Obrigado.

> Ps.: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.9, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using 
>   EditLine wrapper

**Obs.:** Consegui resolver meu problema através desse tutorial:

https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks

Comment: Qual a versão do MySQL e o sistema que está rodando? Tentou utilizar outra versão ou algum binary drop como o MariaDB?

Comment: Em inglês, há uma solução para o seu problema, porém, pode ser diferente, já que é necessário citar o que comentei anteriormente para termos mais detalhes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624774/after-mysql-install-via-brew-i-get-the-error-the-server-quit-without-updating

Comment: @RenanCavalieri editei la com a versao.

Comment: Não sei aonde colocar, mas editei com a resposta q consegui arrumar meu problema!!

Comment: Erick, basta responder normalmente sua pergunta colocando como solucionou o problema :)

Comment: @DiegoFelipe  Obrigado, fiz o que me flw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segui os passo desse link abaixo e consegui resolver meu problema:

https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks

Espero que ajude a todos.

Obrigado.